# How to use the result of one graph in another

Tags: spotfire

I have a bar-graph with averages over time where the last result needs to be input for the calculation of another graph.
[image: Average Machine # in production]
Last value is needed for another graph:
[image: Average product hours]

Where the calculation is
Sum([Dur_per_product]) / **12.61**

The **12.61** should come from the 1st graph.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: are you wanting the graphs to work independently of each other? i.e. the lower graph isn't a details visualization of the top one?

Comment: The idea to have it independently of each other, I would like to use the outcome in other graphs as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the second graph can you try this expression for Value Axis:

Sum[Dur_per_product]/If([Week]=Max([Week]),Sum([# machines over 13 weeks]),0)

If [# machines over 13 weeks] is not a column, and an expression then replace it with expression in the above formula enclosed within the Sum function. Hopefully, it should work.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to enter the expression (with an 'OVER' function in it) but it returns `Please specify an aggregation method`